# Proving A Series is not convergent with little information

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a series Xn, that for all n, `X2n≥n. I have to prove it is not convergent, with only this info. I believe that best way is by contradiction, but cannot quite figure out how. I know I assume an arbitrary L s.t. the abs value(xn - L)< epsilon > 0. Beyond this, I cannot really understand the logic

Comment: Look at the subsequence $\langle x_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.  Is it bounded?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a way to prove by it by contradiction from the definition of convergence.

If we suppose $(x_n)$ does converge to some $0 \leq x\in \mathbb{R}$, one can disprove this by showing that for some $\epsilon > 0$, we have that for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $n> N$ such that $|x_{n}-x| \geq \epsilon$.

Choose $\epsilon := 1$ and consider an arbitrary $N$.

Choose $n=2(N+x) > N$ which by hypothesis we have $x_{2(N+x)} \geq N+x \implies x_{2(N+x)}-x \geq N$ so that $|x_{n} - x| = |x_{2(N+x)}-x| \geq  N\geq 1=\epsilon$. There were some absolute value considerations I was unable to do deal with along the way, but I am sure a similar argument would work for the case where $x < 0$. Then you would have that there does not exist a real number that $(x_{n})$ converges to.

Comment: i think this works pretty well, and i don't believe I need for x<0 as in my class, our sequences are on n in Natural Numbers, not the full reals, and by my sequence's definition (of sorts) ir can't have values below 0 essentially. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! It is customary to upvote and accept your desired answer. Btw, sequences are indexed by the naturals but can commonly have negative elements, e.g.$ -1 , 1 ,-1 ...$